# How can I compress image size, when browse and upload image?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I compress image size, when browse and upload image? I am using .net MVC4.0 and javascript in my project and want compress image size when browse and upload image?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't.
2. Even if you could, compression of binary files (and especially images) is very inefficient and resulting data is usually bigger than the original file.
3. Specialized image compression algorithms (used for JPEG etc.) are not the thing you want, because the original image can't be restored from the results of this kind of compression. Basically you loose quality.
4. You can't.